# charAt - number validation in a string

Tags: java, charat

I have a problem where I need to ensure that the last two digits in a string (called id) are between the numbers of 01 and 40. I thought I had figured it out, however my testing fails when '00' is used - this should fail but it passes.

I know why it is doing this (due to the greater than/less than) but I can't seem to work out how to overcome this problem. Do I need to join characters 10 and 11 together a string then attache further conditional formatting this way?

```
{
if ((id.charAt(10)<='0'&& id.charAt(11)<= '9')
return true;
}
else {
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: That if/else doesn't even begin to attempt to do what you claim you want to achieve. A better approach would be to take the last two characters of the string and try to parse them into a numeric value (i.e. an `int`). If it fails, those characters are not between '01' and '40'. If it doesn't fail, you have a number and you can check if it's in the range from 0 to 40.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method described by 'JustAnotherDeveloper' in the comments (see method `isBetween2` below) but it means you rely on `Integer.parseInt(String)` and on the `NumberFormatException` that may be thrown to define if the 2 characters at index 10 & 11 are numeric or not, which is not really the best solution.

Yous should use regular expressions instead to ensure the two characters are digits (see method `isBetween` below).

Please not that in the example below, the regular expression pattern will accept any alphanumeric characters for the 10 first characters. You will have to modify the pattern if needed.

```
public boolean isBetween(String id) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([[a-zA-Z0-9]]{10})([0-9]{2})");
    Matcher n = p.matcher(id);
    if (n.find()) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(n.group(2));
        return i >= 1 && i <= 40;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isBetween2(String id) {
    String s = id.substring(10, 12);
    int i;
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return i >= 1 && i <= 40;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```